# AndroidStudio: How to move a button in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

How can i move in Android Studio elements like buttons or textViews within a fragment? In an Activity i can take the button with drag&drop, but this seems not to work within fragments. 
So now my button is in the left corner, but i wish to place them in the middle.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.test.fragmenttest.BlankFragment">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: please add the code with your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference if you're using fragments or activities, it's all about your layout type. Try to use ConstraintLayout instead of yours or set `android:gravity="center"` in your FrameLayout.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Or:

```
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: But then its no FrameLayout more

Comment: Is it necessary for you to use FrameLayout?

Comment: Yes, its a requirement for me

Comment: Check it now. Button is in center. But you can't reach draw&drop effect in FrameLayout

Answer (score 0):

set android:gravity="center" in your parent FrameLayout

Comment: I have no parent FrameLayout definied.

Comment: doesn't matter, just add gravity="center" to the parent layout and your button will be centered inside. or, if your parent is relativelayout, you can add "android:layout_ceterHorizontal" in your button view.